# Count SCEditor characters and output below?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, wysiwyg

I am using the real simple wysiwyg editor [SCEditor](http://www.sceditor.com/) for my website.

I am wandering how exactly I can get the current amount of characters in it's textarea and then output them below it?

I [asked on the github](https://github.com/samclarke/SCEditor/issues/116) but it seems not many people use it and the answer didn't make much sense to me, can someone clear it up for me?

The person replied with this:

> var numOfCharacters = $textArea.data("sceditor").val().length;
>
> Where: "$textArea" is a variable with a reference for the textarea DOM
>   element wrapped in a jQuery object.

I have no idea what that means but I'm sure some of you will.

I want to output the length just to some text below the textarea.

Answer (score 2):

you need learn something about jQuery.data .
*jQuery.data* Store arbitrary data associated with the specified element. [read more](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

jQuery plugins like *SCeditor* write their associated datas in *jQuery.data* of element.
for accessing this datas and management, they set their name (like 'sceditor') to it.
when you call `$textArea.data("sceditor")` jQuery return datas that *sceditior* stored in element for you.

when you call `$textArea.data("sceditor").val().length` you are requesting to get val(). it is text of current editor page for $textArea element and length return length of it's text.

Comment: Still confusing to me, do i need to set "$textArea" somehow?

Comment: you must use sceditor with a textarea. this is your DOM element. if you get it by jQuery ( like `var $textarea=$('textarea');` ) it is a **DOM element wrapped in a jQuery object**. now you can call `$textArea.data("sceditor").val().length`

Comment: Thanks that's what I needed to know to get me started since I'm very new to JS.